# Java - Game Animation Techniques

Tags: java, animation, game-physics

So, after ages of searching all I ever keep coming across is spritesheet. I am planning on making a multiplayer game where the changing of items and gear happens regularly. I want to have fun creating new items, but with spritesheets it can get ridiculous redrawing the same movement and having choppy transitions.

cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steam/apps/524970/header.jpg?t=1475608912

Here is the game that kind of inspired me. Very smooth characters and when I watch the animation it is basically just rotating parts, or expanding the image. Am I missing something, or is there an animation technique where you can easily just rotate limbs, or perhaps just expand the image without having to constantly sift through images. Some pseudo code could be ImageWidth = ImageWidth * 1.5 to create a bigger version. Or ImageRotation = 20 where the image rotates at a certain point. Just wanting to know what people use to animate themselves or if you have advice for me.

Comment: I guess you are talking about [Skeletal Animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation), a good example of software is [Spine](http://esotericsoftware.com/)

Comment: [Here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/100453/67680) is a related answer with a implementation of this software in libgdx which points to [this project](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-superspineboy), hope it helps.

Comment: That's a sweet project. I would totally love that type of animation.